# Error when calling camera.setMode(DJICameraMode.shootPhoto)

Tags: dji-sdk

The following situation occurs indeterminately, using Mobile SDK version 4.4 for iOS with a Phantom 4 Pro.  Most often the call to setMode() is successful.  Sometimes however it fails with the following error:

```
Setting parameters operation failed.(code:-1007)
```

There is no difference in the camera state between successful and failed requests.  The request is always made after the same event, which is after a DJIMediaFile download has completed (i.e. DJIMediaFile has called the update block from fetchDat() with isComplete = true.)

What does code -1007 mean and how does one avoid it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please update your iOS [SDK to 4.6](http://Can%20you%20update%20your%20SDK%20to%204.6%20and%20let%20me%20know%20if%20you%20are%20getting%20the%20same%20issue?) and see if you continue to get the error

Comment: this should have been a comment, not an answer